Test out posts with MathJax / $\LaTeX$
Is there a place where I can create posts where I can test out MathJax / $\LaTeX$ support? I've seen this Q/A on how to use MathJax / $\LaTeX$ but I would like to experiment with it and have others get information or provide insights on my attempts.
Note that answers don't have titles, but you can use small $\TeX$ formulas in titles as well. Try and use them sparingly though, as $\TeX$ will slow down rendering of question titles.

Using TikZ to do crypto graphics
Here the reference is obviously the very useful website TikZ for Cryptographers, which provides many examples that can then be adapted and contributed back to the website in order to do nice graphics.
Some of my favorite includes the ones I used in this Garbled Circuit answer:

Or the F function of DES:

Or this nice Elliptic Curve which is finally in a ring of integers modulo $\mathbb{Z}_{89}$ versus the usual representation in $\mathbb{R}$

Notice that in order to use TikZ here, you'll sadly have to download $\LaTeX$ on your computer (or use an online $\LaTeX$ editor that supports TikZ) and run it to produce a PNG image in order to then upload the resulting PNG into your SE answer, since TikZ is not supported on the web version of latex.

Yes, you can create any answer here, where it is out of the way and visible only to other persons that are interested in using $\LaTeX$!

For some reason $\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} 2^i b_i$ doesn't render correctly on GitHub.... Let's see what it does here. It is fine. Dangit.

The question is: $``Can we quote things in comments?''$ Apparently not that way, try $\enquote{Can we quote things in comments?}$. Nope. Uh....

Did I do something wrong? $``Opening and closing quotes''$?

Meh, this is not a good thing bla. That was to be expected. We'll keep to italics I guess.

This is a test (with $$ at start and end; or context see this, or if it fails this).
$$
k\;\overset{ *}\gets\; \{0,1\}\\
k\;\overset{\\\$}\gets\; \{0,1\}\\
k\;\overset{ +}\gets\; \{0,1\}\\
$$
also
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\mathrm{Gen}:&k{\ \overset{\\\$}\gets\ }\{0,\ldots,25\}^t\\
\mathrm{Enc}:&c_i=p_i+k_{i\bmod t}\bmod{26}\\
\mathrm{Dec}:&p_i=c_i-k_{i\bmod t}\bmod{26}
\end{array}$$
also (with $ at start and end)
$
k\;\overset{ *}\gets\; \{0,1\}\\
k\;\overset{\\\$}\gets\; \{0,1\}\\
k\;\overset{ +}\gets\; \{0,1\}\\
$
And this: \\\$ (for context see this).

This formula is fine on the preview, however, not when saved.
Formula: $\mathbf{Adv}^{ind-cca3}_{\pi}(A)=Pr\left[K\overset{\\\$}{\leftarrow}\mathcal{K}:A^{\mathcal{E}_K(\cdot),\mathcal{D}_K(\cdot)}\Rightarrow 1\right] - Pr\left[A^{\mathcal{E}_K(\\\$|\cdot|),\perp(\cdot)}\Rightarrow 1\right] $
To solve: use $$ ... $$
$$\mathbf{Adv}^{ind-cca3}_{\pi}(A)=Pr\left[K\overset{\\\$}{\leftarrow}\mathcal{K}:A^{\mathcal{E}_K(\cdot),\mathcal{D}_K(\cdot)}\Rightarrow 1\right] - Pr\left[A^{\mathcal{E}_K(\\\$|\cdot|),\perp(\cdot)}\Rightarrow 1\right] $$
not solved!
or \small{ ... }
Formula: $\small{\mathbf{Adv}^{ind-cca3}_{\pi}(A)=Pr\left[K\overset{\\\$}{\leftarrow}\mathcal{K}:A^{\mathcal{E}_K(\cdot),\mathcal{D}_K(\cdot)}\Rightarrow 1\right] - Pr\left[A^{\mathcal{E}_K(\\\$|\cdot|),\perp(\cdot)}\Rightarrow 1\right] }$
not solved!
Issue posted on meta.stackexchange.

Alright, so let's see if we can put something down another:
$\underset{1 \leq j \leq n}{\max}\small\text{(the rest of the formula)}$

$\underset{1 \leq j \leq n}{\max}\small\text{(the rest of the formula)}$
Yep, that works fine.
$\overset{}{\max}\small\text{(the rest of the formula)}$

$\overset{}{\max}\small\text{(the rest of the formula)}$
Well, I guessed that one.
Note that you need to use \underset unfortunately as it will be under the text line of what comes next, so the order may seem a bit strange. The owl is really on top, in other words.
